# Loop in Hierarchy to get 1st Element of each level

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class Member 
{    public string header {get;set;}    
     public List<Member> MemberCollection {get;set;} 
}
```

so i have List lstMembers;
that contains like this:

```
MemberA
   |_____ header = HeadingMemberA
   |
   |_____ List<Member> = Member A.1
                    |___ Member A.2
                    |___ Member A.3

MemberB
   |_____ header = HeadingMemberB
   |
   |_____ List<Member> = Member B.1
                    |___ Member B.2
                    |___ Member B.3
```

so now i have to get 1st Member in each level.

list **MemberA, Member A.1, MemberB and Member B.1**

Comment: MemberB is not the first on its level. You need more precise definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
List<Member> firstLevels = new List<Member>();
foreach(Member m in lstMembers)
{
   firstLevels.Add(m);
   firstLevels.Add(m.MemberCollection.First());
}
```

Comment: He also wants `m`, so add `m` before `m.MemberCollection.First();`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that, edited.

Answer (score 0):

well, `Member A` & `Member B` are not first on their level

but if mean to get `Member A.1, Member B.1 ...`

```
members.Select(MemberList => MemberList.MemberCollection.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: MemberA is first on level 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use LINQ then you can build an expression on your collection. Use SelectMany operator with a order by clause.

*Note: following code is just to demonstrate the idea and ignore any syntax /case issue*

```
var members = new List<Member>();
var q = members.SelectMany(m => m.MemberCollection).Orderby(o=>o.Name).FirstOrDefault()
 .ToList();
```